# Handle HttpSession attributes with Springboot Application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, session, redirect, httpsession

I had an old application with Java and Struts.
I do some refactoring and recode this application with SpringBoot.

But I have a problem handling the redirection between application and some external url, keeping my session attribute values.

To simplify, I have two endpoints, one in post, one in get.
First, the POST endpoint is called :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Action.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveConfigurationPost(HttpServletRequest request){
    logger.info("Set session param");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("someAttribute", "value");
    return "redirect:http://external-url.fr@redirectUri=internal-server/Action.do"
}
```

The external website do some treatment, and redirect me back to my application with a get request on the specified uri Action.do

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Action.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String saveConfigurationGet(HttpServletRequest request){
    String myParamValue = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("someAttribute");
    logger.info("Get session param : "+myParamValue); // Return null
    ....
    return "success"
}
```

But after redirect me to the GET endpoint, I always have a null value for my session attribute.
Why ?

With my old application, I used new ActionForward(forwardUrl, true) to redirect.

How could I get the same thing, simple as possible ?

Comment: can you instead try in your redirect method to return `new RedirectView("http://external-url.fr@redirectUri=internal-server/Action.do");` to see if you get the same result?

Comment: Thank you. I tried, same result